# Call a method inside an object with setInterval is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to poll my server using a method inside my object using the `setInterval()` function. The code looks like this:

```
(function(){

    var teacherZone = {

        init: function(){
            this.cacheDOM();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.pollServer(); // get the list of lessons
        },
        cacheDOM: function(){
            this.$showLessons     = $('#showLessons');
            this.$lessonsTemplate = $('#lessonsTemplate');
        },
        bindEvents: function(){

        },
        pollServer: function(){
            alert('Polled');
        }

    }

    teacherZone.init();
    setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer(), 1000)
})();
```

This calls the alert() twice but then no more. Not sure where I am going wrong here.

How do I repeatedly call a method inside an object at a set interval?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
(function(){

    var teacherZone = {

        interval: 5000,

        init: function(){
            this.cacheDOM();
            this.bindEvents();
            setInterval(function(){
                teacherZone.pollServer(); // get the list of lessons
            }, teacherZone.interval);
        },
        cacheDOM: function(){
            this.$showLessons     = $('#showLessons');
            this.$lessonsTemplate = $('#lessonsTemplate');
        },
        bindEvents: function(){

        },
        pollServer: function(){
            alert('Polled');
            // data = {
            //     name: 'John'
            // };
            // this.$showLessons.html(Mustache.render(this.$lessonsTemplate.html(), data));
        }

    }

    teacherZone.init();
    teacherZone.pollServer();

})();
```

Comment: You know what is the difference between a function reference and a function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to the function to `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer, 1000);
```

If you want to be able to use `this` inside the function `pollServer`, then you'll have, either,  to bind `this` to your object using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this:

```
setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer.bind(teacherZone), 1000);
```

or wrap the call to `pollServer` inside an anonimous function like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    teacherZone.pollServer();
}, 1000);
```

because if you don't then `this` will be the parent object of `setInterval` which is the `window` object.

**Edit:**

You can do it in simple way, in case you have to create more instances of `teacherZone` or rename the object `teacherZone` you won't need to rename all the lines that depends on it. Just simply store the value of `this` outside `setInterval` (read about **closures**) like this:

```
init: function(){
    this.cacheDOM();
    this.bindEvents();
    var that = this;       // store this here so it will be accessible inside setInterval
    setInterval(function(){
        that.pollServer(); // use that here (because this will be the window object here so we use that because it holds a reference to the object we want)
    }, this.interval);     // no need to use that here just this will suffice (because here we are inside init not inside the callback of setInterval)
},
```

Now you can rename the object `teacherZone` without worrying!

Comment: Very, very interesting... saved me a lot of time! Thanks I understand now.

Comment: Hi ibrahim, I have updated my question with some new code putting the pollServer function inside an anonymous function inside the object based on your answer... have I got thing right?

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst See the **Edit** section!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Got my research set out.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the parenthesis, because you call the function immediately and do not hand over the function.

```
setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer, 1000)
//                               ^^
```

Comment: Gosh that is interesting! A definite point of research there... always wondered why some functions had no parenthesis.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst no parentheses - you're passing a reference to the method itself. With parenthesis you're executing the method and passing the return value

Comment: Alternative is to always use `function{}` then you won't make the mistake:  `setInterval(function() { teacherZone.pollServer(); }, 1000);`

Comment: there are only two resond for functions without parenthesis, one the above part for hand over a reference the other on is to get an instance with `new` keyword, without the need for parameters.

Comment: @freedomn-m, i would not suggest that style. it adds some overhead without need.

Comment: @JethroHazelhurst it *could* be. If you're passing a reference to a function as a parameter to another function then that could be called a "callback".

Comment: I have updated my code to put the setInterval function INSIDE of the object... I am wondering if I have done this correctly? At least it works and thanks for your help!

Comment: @NinaScholz Correct, but the overhead is minimal compared with maintenance issues when your development team don't know the difference between a function reference and calling a function (as is/was the case here).

Answer (score 2):

You need a function reference instead of calling the function.

Change 
**From:**  `setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer(), 1000)`
**To"**   `setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer, 1000)`

```js
(function(){

    var teacherZone = {

        init: function(){
            this.cacheDOM();
            this.bindEvents();
            this.pollServer(); // get the list of lessons
        },
        cacheDOM: function(){
            this.$showLessons     = $('#showLessons');
            this.$lessonsTemplate = $('#lessonsTemplate');
        },
        bindEvents: function(){

        },
        pollServer: function(){
            alert('Polled');
        }

    }

    teacherZone.init();
    setInterval(teacherZone.pollServer, 1000)
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way :

```
(function(){ 
   $.teacherZone = { 
    init: function(){
        this.cacheDOM();
        this.bindEvents();
        this.pollServer(); 
    },
    cacheDOM: function(){
        this.$showLessons     = $('#showLessons');
        this.$lessonsTemplate = $('#lessonsTemplate');
    },
    bindEvents: function(){

    },
    pollServer: function(){
        console.log('Polled');
    } 
  } 
 $.teacherZone.init(); 
 setInterval($.teacherZone.pollServer, 1000);

})();
```